# Form input not updating API fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Here is my component:

```
const WeatherData = () => {
const [city, setCity] = useState('')
const [unit, setUnit] = useState('imperial');
const [cardData, setCardData] = useState({});
function getForecast() {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=${unit}&appid={hidden}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => setCardData(response))}

    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={getForecast}>
            <input 
                placeholder='Enter City'
                value={city}
                onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type='submit'>Get Forecast</button>
        </form>
        </div>}
```

My issue is that when I type in a city to my input and then click the submit button it won't update the {city} state for the getForecast function. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you reload the entire page, which cancels the `fetch` request and resets everything to the default.

Capture the event object and prevent the default behaviour.

```
function getForecast(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch...
```